# Swift 3.0 converting error

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, swift3

I have converted Swift 2.2 code to Swift 3.0, but I'm getting the following error.

```
open func saveToPath(_ path: String, format: ImageFormat, compressionQuality: Double) -> Bool
{
    if let image = getChartImage(transparent: format != .jpeg) {
        var imageData: Data!
        switch (format)
        {
        case .png:
            imageData = NSUIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
            break

        case .jpeg:
            imageData = NSUIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, CGFloat(compressionQuality))
            break
        }

        let url = NSURL(string: path)
        return imageData.write(to: url as! URL, options: true)
    }
    return false
}
```

error :

> Cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type
>    'data.writeOptions' (aka 'NSData.writingOptions'))

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: This method has changed: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1410595-write

Comment: Also, you cast NSURL to URL, but you should just use URL directly.

Comment: Pass `[]` to options instead of `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two lines need to be fixed:

```
let url = NSURL(string: path)
return imageData.write(to: url as! URL, options: true)
```

1. Use `URL`, not `NSURL`.
2. Use the proper initializer to convert a file path string into a file URL.
3. Pass the proper value to the `options` parameter.

The fixed code should be like:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
return imageData.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
```